# Integration help - find $f(x)$ (2nd derivative is $f''(x)=6x+6$, stationary point at $(3,19))$

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I've done part a, it's a local minimum as substituting 3 into $f''(x)$ gives a value > 0.

However, for the 2nd part, here's my working so far.

$f'(x)=\int 6x+6 \ dx=3x^2+6x+c$

$f(x)=\int3x^2+6x+c \ dx = x^3+3x^2+cx+c$

I substituted 3 and 9 in, so:
$19=(3)^3+3(3)^2+(3)c+c$

$-35=4c$ which doesn't look right.

The answer in the back says:

$f(x)=x^3+3x^2-45x+100$

I am going wrong somewhere, can someone help please>

Comment: When you integrate $f'$you're adding $c$, the constant can very well be different as you can see by the final answers. You should use another letter.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\int\left(\int(6x+6)dx\right)dx=\int(3x^2+6x+c_1)dx=x^3+3x^2+c_1x+c_2$$

Comment: Thanks - I've been thinking for a while and am not sure on what to do next. Am I meant to substitute in?

I get $-35=c_1x+c_2$. What's the next step?

Comment: @Jim The fact that $3$ is a minimum point of $f$, tells you something about the behavior of $f'$ around $3$.

Comment: $3\cdot3^2+6\cdot3+c_1=0\Rightarrow c_1=-45$